# Python Multi Requests URLs

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, curl, async-await

**Hi Guys,**
im new with python (im just begining less than 2 weeks)
so i need some advices and tricks :p

what is the fastest and most efficient way to fetch around 1500 api request ?

1. use async function that execute them all and return to get the
       results ?
2. dividing them into lists of 300 urls and put every
       list inside a Thread which will execute them inside an async loop ?
3. do the same thing as the second suggestion but with Processes
       instead of Threads ?

**for the moment it's working for me but it takes something like 8s to execute 1400 api requests  but when i try a single request without threads it takes 9s
im i doing something wrong ??!**

## Fetch one URL ( i tried to pass the Session as param but i get errors when  reachs the 700 requests )

```
async def fetch_one(url):
    async with curio_http.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await session.get(url)
        content =  await response.json()
        return  content
```

## fetch a list of URLs inside an async loop

```
async def fetchMultiURLs(url_list):
        tasks = []
        responses = []
        for url in url_list:
            task = await curio.spawn(fetch_one(url))
            tasks.append(task)

        for task in tasks:
            content = await task.join()
            responses.append(content)
            print(content)
```

## Create Threads and put inside them Async Loops depending on URLs / X URL by Loop

## for example MultiFetch(URLS[600],200) will create 3 threads that will call 200 requests by thread and in async way

```
def MultiFetch(URLS,X):
    MyThreadsList = []
    MyThreadsResults = []
    N_Threads = (lambda x:  int (x/X) if (x % X == 0) else int(x/X)+1) (len(URLS))
    for i in range( N_Threads  ): # will iterate X = ListSize / X
              MyThreadsList.append( Thread(  target = curio.run , args = (fetchMultiURLs( (URLS[ i*X:(X*i+X)]) )  ,)    )  )
              MyThreadsList[i].start()
    for i in range( N_Threads  ):
              MyThreadsResults.append(MyThreadsList[i].join())
    return MyThreadsResults
```

Comment: Many threads + Queue is the fastest i know. (3 million http requests + scan in an hour)

Comment: Thank you very much for you Answer :)
but It's not the most efficient way cause in Python the GIL problem is slowing too much this kind of requests :p (i tried you idea and it takes 11s to do it )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finaly i found a solution :)** it takes 2.2s to fetch 1400 urls

i used the 3ed suggestion  ( async loop inside Processes )

**# Fetch 1 URL**

```
async def fetch_one(url):
    async with curio_http.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await session.get(url)
        content =  await response.json()
        return  content
```

**# Fetch X URLs**
    async def fetchMultiURLs(url_list):
            tasks = []
            responses = []
            for url in url_list:
                task = await curio.spawn(fetch_one(url))
                tasks.append(task)

```
        for task in tasks:
            content = await task.join()
            responses.append(content)
        return responses
```

**# i tried to put lambda instead of this function but it not working**

```
def RuningCurio(X):
    return curio.run(fetchMultiURLs(X))
```

**# Create Processes and Async Loops depending on URLs / X URL by Loop**

**# in my case (im using a VPS) a single Process can easly fetch 700 links in less than 1s , so dont make multiProcesses under this number of urls (just use the fetchMultiURLs function)**

```
 def MultiFetch(URLS,X):
    MyListofLists = []
    LengthURLs = len(URLS)
    N_Process = int (LengthURLs / X) if ( LengthURLs % X == 0) else int( LengthURLs / X) + 1
    for i in range( N_Process  ): # Create a list of lists (  [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ] )
        MyListofLists.append(URLS[ i*X:(X*i+X)])
    P = Pool( N_Process) 
    return  P.map( RuningCurio ,MyListofLists)
```

**# im fetching 2100 urls in 1.1s i hope this Solution will help you Guys**